# Customer Display OR Pole Display

Tags: vb.net

I do also want to know how can I Display Text on Pole Display.

I write the code with VB.net 2008.

Sample Code that I write is :

```
If SerialPort1.IsOpen = False Then SerialPort1.Open()
SerialPort1.Write("\r\n" & RichTextBox1.Text & vbCr, 0, RichTextBox1.TextLength)
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
If SerialPort1.IsOpen = True Then SerialPort1.Close()
```

I got no errors but can't display on Pole Display.
Please help me.

---

Sorry,

Forgot to Say. I do setup the Serial port Like This:

```
    SerialPort1.BaudRate = 1200
    SerialPort1.Parity = IO.Ports.Parity.None
    SerialPort1.StopBits = 1
    SerialPort1.DataBits = 7
```

But It doesn't work.  :(

Comment: why are you sleeping and closing the serial port ?    Remove the sleep statement and leave the serial port open you may be closing the port before all the data has been sent

Comment: If you registered your account you'd be able to edit your own question.

Comment: I've merged your three accounts.  At least the three I found.  Please consider registering so that you don't create any more

Answer (score 3):

```
sp = new SerialPort("COM1", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
sp.Open();
// to clear the display
sp.Write(Convert.ToString((char)12));

// first line goes here
sp.WriteLine("Total : " + textBox1.Text + " RM" );

// 2nd line goes here

sp.WriteLine((char)13 + "Tendered:" + textBox2.Text + " RM");

sp.Close();
sp.Dispose();
sp = null;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    Dim sp As SerialPort = New SerialPort("COM15", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One)
    sp.Open()
    sp.Write(Convert.ToString(ChrW(12)))
    sp.WriteLine("WELCOME HERE")
    sp.WriteLine(ChrW(13) & "Total Amount:1200")
    sp.Close()
    sp.Dispose()
    sp = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup the serial port -  i.e. the baud rate, number of bits and number of stop bits.  Read the display poles manual to get these settings.

**edit**

**Before you write any code use a terminal program like windows hyper-terminal to confirm:**

1. That your hardware is working.
2. if you are using the correct com port
3. if you are using the correct baud rate
4. If you need flow control (XON/XOF) or is it via hardware (RTS/CTS)
5. What commands you can send to the display- i.e. to clear the display & to move the top line
6. if the display pole dip switches are set-up correctly